# Error Your version of SQLite (3.7.17) is too old. Active Record supports SQLite >= 3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems

I have just upgraded from rails 5.2 to rails 6 and when I try to do anything with the app the above error is thrown.

I am using sqlite3 for development in the gem file and the old app was working just fine but after the upgrade, the error keeps getting thrown .

```
group :development do 
  gem 'sqlite3'   #gem to use in development environment
end

group :production do 
 gem 'pg'         #gem to use in production environment
 #gem 'fog'
end
```

That is what is my gem file

Comment: Which type of Linux are you using?

Comment: Hello @bradpotts

Comment: I am using cloud9 IDE and here are the details of the version

Comment: NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

Comment: Oh cool I use Cloud9 as well. I would create another environment, after the title, hit next step, on the second page near the bottom has Amazon Linux or Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS option. Pick Ubuntu and you'll be up and running. From what I read Amazon Linux next to impossible to update Sqlite3 without breaking something and may take too much effort. Someone might chime in with a solution but this is what I came up with to get going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I switched my dev machine over to Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS which has a higher version of Sqlite 3.22 which is not the latest but run Rails 6 just fine.

[image: Ubuntu Option Cloud9]