# Version of SQLite (3.7.17) is too old. Active Record supports SQLite >= 3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run Rails 6 in my EC2 instance, but I am encountering the following error:

`Your version of SQLite (3.7.17) is too old. Active Record supports SQLite >= 3.8.`

If it matters:
- I have the following in my gem file: `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4`
- I am using the following command: `rvmsudo rails server -p 80 -b 0.0.0.0`
- When I run `rails s` locally I do not encounter the issue.

This is the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086629/error-your-version-of-sqlite-3-7-17-is-too-old-active-record-supports-sqlite), but the selected answer was specific to using AWS Cloud9.

**EDIT:**

Here are the results after running `sudo yum install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 software-properties-common`:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package build-essential available.
No package libsqlite3-dev available.
No package sqlite3 available.
No package software-properties-common available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Here are the results after after running `sudo yum install libsqlite3-dev` and `sudo yum install sqlite3`, respectively:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package libsqlite3-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package sqlite3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**EDIT 2:**
When running `rails db:migrate` I see this:

```
warning Skipping preferred cache folder "/home/ec2-user/.cache/yarn" because it is not writable.
warning Selected the next writable cache folder in the list, will be "/tmp/.yarn-cache-1000".
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rails aborted!
Your version of SQLite (3.7.17) is too old. Active Record supports SQLite >= 3.8
```

Comment: In your EC2 instance run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 software-properties-common`, this will update the `sqlite` version

Comment: @allenbrkn My instance uses `yum`, so I replaced `apt-get` with `yum` for both of those but nothing updated. I have pasted the result in my original post.

Comment: For yum try running `sudo yum install sqlite libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-devel`, If it doesn't work - `sudo yum update sqlite libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-devel`. If both won't work - `sudo yum upgrade sqlite libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-devel`

Comment: @allenbrkn No luck. I am seeing the following when I start up the server, but I'm guessing that doesn't have anything to do with it: ```Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.```

Comment: I guess I could try to use a different database?

Comment: I think that is not required. This problem is in `rvm` not in `sqlite`. Did you run this command `export rvmsudo_secure_path=0` and restarted the `rails server`?

Comment: @allenbrkn When I switch to `rvmsudo_secure_path=0` then try to use rvm it tells me it doesn't exist. I have pasted some additional details in the original post.

Answer (score 13):

Instruction for updeting for `Centos7`:

```
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2019/sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz

tar xzvf sqlite-autoconf-3290000.tar.gz

cd sqlite-autoconf-3290000

./configure --prefix=/opt/sqlite/sqlite3

make

sudo make install

/opt/sqlite/sqlite3/bin/sqlite3 --version

gem uninstall sqlite3

gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=/opt/sqlite/sqlite3/include \ --with-sqlite3-lib=/opt/sqlite/sqlite3/lib
```

Comment: Require more details to answer this question.

Comment: to install gem using bundle (Gemfile), you have to change the last two steps to:

`bundle config build.sqlite3 --with-sqlite3-include=/opt/sqlite/sqlite3/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/opt/sqlite/sqlite3/lib`

`bundle install`

Answer (score 6):

This worked perfectly for me:

```bash
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/sqlite/3.8.11/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-devel-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm`
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/sqlite/3.8.11/1.fc21/x86_64/sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm`
sudo yum install sqlite-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm sqlite-devel-3.8.11-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

If after MartenCatcher answer you still get the same error, most likely you will need to (for CentOs 7)

```
# Replace system low version sqlite3
mv /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3_old
ln -s /opt/sqlite/sqlite3/bin/sqlite3 /usr/bin/sqlite3
echo "/opt/sqlite/sqlite3/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/sqlite3.conf
ldconfig
sqlite3 -version
```

Answer (score -5):

If you have admin access to EC2 instance , Run these

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Comment: My instance uses yum, so I replaced apt-get with yum for both of those but nothing updated. I have pasted the result in my original post.