# How to see the application you're creating on cloud9 using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

So I'm trying to use cloud9 on AWS to learn some web development stuff. I'm going through a course that's walking me through creating a web application. It says that you're supposed to be able to click "preview" and it will just show it to you. When I do this it says

> To allow requests to 781d5d3f50664f608bb52439726f4248.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com, add the following to your environment configuration:
> config.hosts << "781d5d3f50664f608bb52439726f4248.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"

I've looked everywhere and watched 10 videos about it but nothing works to be able to see the thing I'm making. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6 includes some middleware to help prevent DNS Rebinding attacks. When running in the development environment, the default configuration is to allow only 'localhost' access. The Cloud9 preview function, however, uses the fully qualified public domain name of your app, which Rails then blocks. As the error message says, you can address this by appending your app's host explicitly to `config/environment/development.rb`:

```rb
config.hosts << "781d5d3f50664f608bb52439726f4248.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
```

It's been a while since I used Cloud9, but if you continue to have an issue with Preview after you've added the host to the whitelist, try pasting the link in the Preview pane into a new browser tab.

Comment: Now its saying that my version of SQLite is old but I don't even know where that was downloaded. How do I update that?

Comment: The canned Cloud9 image pre-loads various packages, includes sqlite3 (and Rails 5 for that matter). I think you are correct that the pre-loaded version of sqlite doesn't work with Rails 6, but you should be able to upgrade the package. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58073262/version-of-sqlite-3-7-17-is-too-old-active-record-supports-sqlite-3-8) to see if that helps any.